# Getting Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied error

Tags: geoserver

When I'm trying to containerizing the geoserver web app using docker. I'm getting below error ERROR [security.impl] - Failed to reload data access rules from layers.properties, keeping old rules
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create security/layers.properties,
can anyone help me on containerizing the geoserver web app using docker.

**Docker configuration.**

```
`FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty:latest

# Add application code under /var/lib/jetty/webapps directory
COPY target/geoserver/ /var/lib/jetty/webapps/geoserver
EXPOSE 8080'
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: First check you actually have permission to write to `/var/lib/jetty/webapps/geoserver`, then you need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Ha Ian Turton, I don't have permissions to write /var/lib/jetty/webapps/geoserver. how can I get those requests.